# Return 2 records from Select Statement with different Where Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wanted to return 2 separate records using 1 select statement with different  WHERE clauses.  I need assistance with the proper syntax or commands

my columns are: `qDate`, `qTicker`, `qClose`

```
SELECT
qClose (qDate = #5/15/2015#) AS FirstClose,
qClose (qDate = #5/10/2015#) AS SecondClose,
FROM Quotes
WHERE qTicker = "A";
```

here is the table structure

```
qDate, qTicker, qClose
5/15/2015, A, 45.00
5/14/2015, A, 43.50
5/10/2015, A, 42.00
```

I want something like this:

```
qTicker  FirstClose   SecondClose 
A        42.00        45.00
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: DBMS is Access but using SQL module.  i want to return 2 data points, so the qClose for first date "FirstClose", and the qClose for the second date "SecondClose"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the value of `qClose` for a given `qTicker` on two different dates returned in the same row, right?

You'll need something similar to this (although I don't know your setup so it won't be this exactly):

```
SELECT first.qTicker, FirstClose, SecondClose,
(FirstClose - SecondClose) as CloseDifference
FROM
(
    SELECT qTicker, qClose as FirstClose FROM Quotes
    WHERE qDate = #5/15/2015#
) first
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT qTicker, qClose as SecondClose FROM Quotes
    WHERE qDate = #5/10/2015#
) second
ON
first.qTicker = second.qTicker
WHERE
first.qTicker = "A"
```

I've even given you a difference column.

Comment: i just added more commentary to my original post with sample table.  i tried this  and it errored out, asking for a parameter. please see my newly added comments (its listed under my original post)

Comment: Given your clarification (which should be an edit to your post, not an answer) it looks like I guessed correctly what you wanted. Give the exact error message, and I'll be able to fix it. Also: are you in Access or some other database?

Comment: i am using SQL within MS Access.  Its returning the correct closing prices for the given dates.  But it also returns both closing prices for every symbol in my table, So its not specific to a particular symbol. (in my example I used "A" as the ticker.

Comment: Updated my answer to only give you "A". Easy!

Answer (score 2):

```
    Select
    qCl (qDate = #5/15/2015#) as FirstClose,
    qCl (qDate = #5/10/2015#) as SecondClose
    from Quotes
    WHERE --condition
    union all
    Select
    qCl (qDate = #5/15/2015#) as FirstClose,
    qCl (qDate = #5/10/2015#) as SecondClose
    from Quotes
    WHERE --condition
```

This may be what you need

Comment: Not what the OP was looking for. Although the original question was pretty confusing so I understand why you thought it was!